# How To Make 3D Script Work With 2D (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I have a script that shoots an arrow when you click and drag, kinda like Angry Birds.
I want it to work with the 2D RigidBody and 2D collider but when I change the rigidbody.AddForce to rigidbody2D.AddForce, It doesn't work.

How can I fix this to work for 2D?

I also want the arrow to rotate in 2D space either up or down depending on where mouse is pulled back. When I try the mouse look script, it rotates it in the z axis (I think) and distorts the arrow. Any easy solution to fix this??

Thanks guys. I'm new to game making and I've been trying to figure this stuff out for like the last 10 hours. I need some pros to help!
Thanks!!!

Heres my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragShotMover2 : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxDragLength = 2; // this is the base magnitude and the maximum length of the line drawn in the user interface
public float maxMultiplier = 5; // multiply the line length by this to allow for higher force values to be represented by shorter lines 
public Vector3 dragPlaneNormal = Vector3.up; // a vector describing the orientation of the drag plan relative to world-space but centered on the target
public SnapDir snapDirection = SnapDir.away; // force is applied either toward or away from the mouse on release
public ForceMode forceTypeToApply = ForceMode.VelocityChange;

public bool  overrideVelocity = true; // cancel the existing velocity before applying the new force
public bool  pauseOnDrag = true; // causes the simulation to pause when the object is clicked and unpause when released

public Color noForceColor = Color.yellow; // color of the visualization helpers at force 0
public Color maxForceColor = Color.red; // color of the visualization helpers at maximum force

public enum SnapDir {toward, away}

private Vector3 forceVector;
private float magPercent = 0;

private bool  mouseDragging = false;
private Vector3 mousePos3D;
private float dragDistance;
private Plane dragPlane;
private Ray mouseRay;
private GameObject dragZone;

private string shaderString = "Transparent/Diffuse";
private Material dzMat;

void  Start (){
    Color currentColor = noForceColor;
    dzMat = new Material(Shader.Find(shaderString));

    // create the dragzone visual helper
    dragZone = new GameObject("dragZone_" + gameObject.name);
    dragZone.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = MakeDiscMeshBrute(maxDragLength/4);
    //dragZone.GetComponent.MeshFilter.
    dragZone.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    dragZone.renderer.enabled = false;

    dragZone.name = "dragZone_" + gameObject.name;
    dragZone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(maxDragLength*2, 0.025f, maxDragLength*2);
    dragZone.renderer.material = dzMat;
    dragZone.renderer.material.color = currentColor * new Color(1,1,1,0.2f);

    // create the dragplane
    dragPlane = new Plane(dragPlaneNormal, transform.position);

    // orient the drag plane
    if (dragPlaneNormal != Vector3.zero) {
        dragZone.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dragPlaneNormal) * new Quaternion(1, 0, 0, 1);
    } 
    else Debug.LogError("Drag plane normal cannot be equal to Vector3.zero.");

    //update the position of the dragzone
    dragZone.transform.position = transform.position;   
}

void  OnMouseDown (){
    mouseDragging = true;

    if (pauseOnDrag) {
        // pause the simulation
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
    // update the dragplane
    dragPlane = new Plane(dragPlaneNormal, transform.position);

    // orient the drag plane
    if (dragPlaneNormal != Vector3.zero) {
        dragZone.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dragPlaneNormal) * new Quaternion(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else Debug.LogError("Drag plane normal cannot be equal to Vector3.zero.");

    //update the position of the dragzone
    dragZone.transform.position = transform.position;

    dragZone.renderer.enabled = true;
}



void  OnMouseDrag (){
    Color currentColor = noForceColor;
    // update the plane if the target object has left it
    if (dragPlane.GetDistanceToPoint(transform.position) != 0) {
        // update dragplane by constructing a new one -- I should check this with a profiler
        dragPlane = new Plane(dragPlaneNormal, transform.position);
    }

    // create a ray from the camera, through the mouse position in 3D space
    mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    // if mouseRay intersects with dragPlane
    float intersectDist = 0.0f;

    if (dragPlane.Raycast(mouseRay, out intersectDist)) {
        // update the world space point for the mouse position on the dragPlane
        mousePos3D = mouseRay.GetPoint(intersectDist);

        // calculate the distance between the 3d mouse position and the object position
        dragDistance = Mathf.Clamp((mousePos3D - transform.position).magnitude, 0, maxDragLength);

        // calculate the force vector
        if (dragDistance*maxMultiplier < 1) dragDistance = 0; // this is to allow for a "no move" buffer close to the object
        forceVector = mousePos3D - transform.position;
        forceVector.Normalize();
        forceVector *= dragDistance * maxMultiplier;

        // update color the color
        // calculate the percentage value of current force magnitude out of maximum
        magPercent = (dragDistance * maxMultiplier) / (maxDragLength * maxMultiplier);
        // choose color based on how close magPercent is to either 0 or max
        currentColor = noForceColor * (1-magPercent) + maxForceColor * magPercent;

        // dragzone color
        dragZone.renderer.material.color = currentColor * new Color(1,1,1,0.2f);

        // draw the line
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forceVector / maxMultiplier, currentColor);
    }

    //update the position of the dragzone
    dragZone.transform.position = transform.position;
}

void  OnMouseUp (){
    mouseDragging = false;

    if (overrideVelocity) {
        // cancel existing velocity
        rigidbody.AddForce(-rigidbody.velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

    }

    // add new force
    int snapD = 1;
    if (snapDirection == SnapDir.away) snapD = -1; // if snapdirection is "away" set the force to apply in the opposite direction
    rigidbody.AddForce(snapD * forceVector, forceTypeToApply);

    // cleanup
    dragZone.renderer.enabled = false;

    if (pauseOnDrag) {
        // un-pause the simulation
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

}

void  OnGUI (){
    if (mouseDragging) {
        Vector2 guiMouseCoord = GUIUtility.ScreenToGUIPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        GUI.Box ( new Rect(guiMouseCoord.x-30, Screen.height-guiMouseCoord.y+15, 100, 20), "force: "+Mathf.Round((forceVector).magnitude));
    }
}

Mesh MakeDiscMeshBrute ( float r  ){
    Mesh discMesh;
    Vector3[] dmVerts = new Vector3[18];
    Vector3[] dmNorms = new Vector3[18];
    Vector2[] dmUVs = new Vector2[18];
    int[] dmTris = new int[48];
    int i = 0;

    discMesh = new Mesh();

    dmVerts[0] = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    dmVerts[1] = new Vector3(0,0,r);
    dmVerts[2] = new Vector3(1,0,1).normalized * r; // find the vector at the correct distance the hacky-hillbilly way!
    dmVerts[3] = new Vector3(r,0,0);
    dmVerts[4] = new Vector3(1,0,-1).normalized * r;
    dmVerts[5] = new Vector3(0,0,-r);
    dmVerts[6] = new Vector3(-1,0,-1).normalized * r;
    dmVerts[7] = new Vector3(-r,0,0);
    dmVerts[8] = new Vector3(-1,0,1).normalized * r;

    // set the other side to the same points
    for (i = 0; i<dmVerts.Length/2; i++) {
        dmVerts[dmVerts.Length/2 + i] = dmVerts[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i<dmNorms.Length; i++) {
        if (i<dmNorms.Length/2) dmNorms[i] = Vector3.up; // set side one to face up
        else dmNorms[i] = -Vector3.up; // set side two to face down
    }

    dmUVs[0] = new Vector2(0,0);
    dmUVs[1] = new Vector2(0,r);
    dmUVs[2] = new Vector2(1,1).normalized * r;;
    dmUVs[3] = new Vector2(r,0);
    dmUVs[4] = new Vector2(1,-1).normalized * r;;
    dmUVs[5] = new Vector2(0,-r);
    dmUVs[6] = new Vector2(-1,-1).normalized * r;;
    dmUVs[7] = new Vector2(-r,0);
    dmUVs[8] = new Vector2(-1,1).normalized * r;;

    // set the other side to the same points
    for (i = 0; i<dmUVs.Length/2; i++) {
        dmUVs[dmUVs.Length/2 + i] = dmUVs[i];
    }

    dmTris[0] = 0;
    dmTris[1] = 1;
    dmTris[2] = 2;

    dmTris[3] = 0;
    dmTris[4] = 2;
    dmTris[5] = 3;

    dmTris[6] = 0;
    dmTris[7] = 3;
    dmTris[8] = 4;

    dmTris[9] = 0;
    dmTris[10] = 4;
    dmTris[11] = 5;

    dmTris[12] = 0;
    dmTris[13] = 5;
    dmTris[14] = 6;

    dmTris[15] = 0;
    dmTris[16] = 6;
    dmTris[17] = 7;

    dmTris[18] = 0;
    dmTris[19] = 7;
    dmTris[20] = 8;

    dmTris[21] = 0;
    dmTris[22] = 8;
    dmTris[23] = 1;

    // side two
    dmTris[24] = 9;
    dmTris[25] = 11;
    dmTris[26] = 10;

    dmTris[27] = 9;
    dmTris[28] = 12;
    dmTris[29] = 11;

    dmTris[30] = 9;
    dmTris[31] = 13;
    dmTris[32] = 12;

    dmTris[33] = 9;
    dmTris[34] = 14;
    dmTris[35] = 13;

    dmTris[36] = 9;
    dmTris[37] = 15;
    dmTris[38] = 14;

    dmTris[39] = 9;
    dmTris[40] = 16;
    dmTris[41] = 15;

    dmTris[42] = 9;
    dmTris[43] = 17;
    dmTris[44] = 16;

    dmTris[45] = 9;
    dmTris[46] = 10;
    dmTris[47] = 17;

    discMesh.vertices = dmVerts;
    discMesh.uv = dmUVs;
    discMesh.normals = dmNorms;
    discMesh.triangles = dmTris;

    return discMesh;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi iEpic, have you had this working in 3D? if you are working with the new 2D features in Unity3D then rotating it on the Z axis is the correct way to do it. Maybe if you post a picture of what the distortion looks like we can try to figure out... Also please post your error message

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the 3D Rigidbody, I'd suggest just using [RigidbodyConstraints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html), so you can lock the z (or whatever) axis/rotation, and it will perform exactly the same as a 2D platformer.